# Vagrant up error: superclass mismatch for class ImageNotConfiguredError

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to get Vagrant to work. I installed everything but when I run "vagrant up" in the terminal, I get the following error

```
 $ vagrant up
/Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/errors.rb:6:in `<module:Errors>': superclass mismatch for class ImageNotConfiguredError (TypeError)
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/errors.rb:5:in `<module:DockerProvider>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/errors.rb:4:in `<module:VagrantPlugins>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/errors.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/action.rb:9:in `require_relative'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/action.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/provider.rb:2:in `require_relative'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/provider.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/plugin.rb:16:in `require_relative'
from /Users/charleswang1104/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/docker-provider-0.1.0/lib/docker-provider/plugin.rb:16:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/plugin.rb:193:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/plugin.rb:193:in `block in provider'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:27:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:27:in `get'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `block in each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:47:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:47:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:272:in `default_provider'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:165:in `block in with_target_vms'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `call'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `block in with_target_vms'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `each'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `with_target_vms'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:67:in `block in execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:238:in `block (2 levels) in batch'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:236:in `tap'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:236:in `block in batch'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:235:in `synchronize'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:235:in `batch'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:58:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:252:in `cli'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.1/bin/vagrant:166:in `<main>'
```

Please let me know how I can fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: you are using docker provision, i think when you change to virtual box you will avoid this bug

Comment: OP is using the docker *provider* plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Just run the following command:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall docker-provider
```